# Transition between posts not refund to the list of all posts

Tags: react-admin

i use React-admin. And I should add on the page "Edit", for example, products, two buttons.
That on clicking the corresponding button it was possible to pass to the next or previous products not refund to the list of all products. Is it possible in react-admin?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJrc7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can [create your own actions component](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#actions)